# Get route params in RESTful controller

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

In my `RestController` which extends `AbstractRestfulController`, I can get the route params in the implemented functions such as...

```
public function create($data)
{
    $entity = $this->params()->fromRoute('entity');
}
```

... but when I do the same in the constructor like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $entity = $this->params()->fromRoute('entity');
}
```

I get `Call to a member function getParam() on a non-object`.

Why is that? How can I get the route parameters in the constructor?

---

#### What I am trying to do

Since I'm trying to create a generic controller, there is a part of the restful route that is shared for all actions (resp. verbs). The entity for which the request is made. I'd like to store this in a class parameter for convenience.

Comment: None of the components have been injected when the call to the `__construct`or is made, that happens after the controller is initialized by the controller manager. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The edit hasn't made things any clearer. What exactly do you want to do with the `$entity` you're attempting to assign the `entity` param to in your constructor?

Comment: No, as I wrote, I want to store it as class field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd write a method to proxy to whatever value you need, and just call that method, it's only a little more expensive to call `$this->getEntity()` than it is to call `$this->entity`, which, as far as I can tell is the stated aim

```
class RestController 
{
    protected $entity;

    public function getEntity()
    {
        if (!$this->entity) {
            $this->entity = $this->params()->fromRoute('entity');
        }
        return $this->entity;
    }
}
```

If you really do want to pre-populate the entity property, the simplest method is to use an initializer, and move the code from your `__construct`or to `init()`. Have your controller implement `\Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface`

```
use Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface;

class RestController extends AbstractRestfulController implements InitializableInterface
{
    protected $entity;

    public function init() {
        $this->entity = $this->params()->fromRoute('entity');
    }
}
```

Add an initializer to the controller loader in your module boostrap

```
use Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)

        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $controllers = $sm->get('ControllerLoader');            

        $controllers->addInitializer(function($controller, $cl) {
            if ($controller instanceof InitializableInterface) {
                $controller->init();
            }
        }, false); // false tells the loader to run this initializer after all others
    }
}
```

Comment: ZF2 is just so complex and complicated... I really start thinking more and more that it has crossed the over-engineering threshold and isn't useful for mere mortals anymore, especially given the lack of detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That would not make any sense as the route is matched to a particular action.

You can't route to a constructor, therefore how could you get route parameters there?

If you give an idea of what you are trying to do then I could suggest a better/nicer way to do it

Comment: I'd be glad to know of a better way to do what I'm trying to do :)